# The physics of bottle flipping

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Recently it has become a trend to flip a bottle which is partially filled with water and land it on it's bottom. This video shows the phenomena :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2E7rS1q4NbU

What i would like to know is that can we model this phenomena to come up with an equation for a perfect flip of the bottle. If the phenomena does not take a shape in your mind you can ask me to illustrate it much clearly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flipping a bottle](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/151001). See also [Water bottle moment of inertia](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133672) and  [Why does the water bottle not rotate when it is half full?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/185590)

Answer (score -1):

Like the previous craze for [flipping a paper/plastic cup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip_cup), I think it is mostly a matter of practice to flip at the right speed to get the bottle to land on its base. When it does so, the bottle containing 1/3 water has the most stability. But many of the clips show bottles half-filled landing upright, so the amount of water is not crucial.

The larger the number of rotations before landing and the higher aspect ratio of the bottle (height/base), the more difficult it is to land the bottle successfully.

The [Institute of Physics explanation](http://www.iop.org/resources/topic/archive/water-bottle-flip/page_68405.html) points out that when optimally filled and flipped at the right speed the bottle almost stops rotating as it lands. This is compared with a diver who increases his/her moment of inertia in order to open out from the initial tight spin into a slow rotation on reaching the water.

Comment: Why the down-vote?